# How to Attach Handjoints into MRTK Rigged Hands?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I had set of 27 Hand Joint positions per hand. I want to attach 27 Hand joints into Rigged hands in Unity.
For this I've referred this Doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2022-05
[image]

As you can see above image. I was able to show my hands in unity and HoloLens2 like this. I want to move all joints as per user’s hand movements which I am able to do. But here, instead of showing just the hand joints of the user, I want to show Rigged Hands of MRTK.

[image]

Above image of Rigged Hands is provided by MRTK. Now I want to know how to attach hand joints to these prefabs. So that I can move my Rigged Hands as per user’s hand movements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to display both the hand joints and the rigged hand. Then you just need to turn it on by setting **Hand Mesh Visualization Modes** and **Hand Joint Visualization Modes** according to [Hand visualization settings - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#hand-visualization-settings), as shown in the following picture. The operation of attaching the hand joints to the rigged hand is performed automatically by MRTK.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

We are using Photon for Multiuser Collaboration in our Mixed Reality Application. Will this work with photon also? Because I tried and didn't get success.

Comment: Do you mean you want the rigged hand to be visible to other players in multiplayer? If so, MRTK doesn't provide an out-of-the-box method (feel free to use the hand mesh/model from MRTK), you need to manually instantiate the rigged hand prefab using the method in Photon and map the local player's rigged hand transform and joint transforms one by one to the prefab. The above setup should allow you to see the rigged hand locally, if it doesn't work as expected, please provide your Unity version and MRTK version.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I’ve created a Prefab of Rigged hand Model and that Prefab I’m using in My project. While using that prefab, In “Rigged Hand Visualizer” Script I’m facing an error like this: 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.BaseHandVisualizer.Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityHandJointHandler.OnHandJointsUpdated

Could you please suggest how to solve this?, If not then is there any other way to use Rigged Hands Prefab ?

Comment: This script is used by MRTK to track and control the visualization of the rigged hand. And by design, HoloLens 2 can only track two hands of the current user. What I mean above is that you can use the model provided by MRTK, but you need to implement how to track hands and joints yourself.

Comment: This may help & answered over on the MRTK team github:  https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/11257   "If you want to animate hands for other networked players, you'll have to build your own hand rig and query our hand tracking API yourself."